# How to create frame widgets in tkinter python based on MySQL table for shop app?

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

So I would like to create a shopping app in which I have already made the code by which the admin of app can add products to a MySQL table and then left is to display the products like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tl68e.png)

These products will be stored in a frame and frames are to be placed in a canvas with which we can scroll through frames. Now the issue I am facing how will I dynamically, based on number of products in MySQL table add "Add to Cart" and frames as it (I guess) is not possibly easy to dynamically create Identifiers for Tkinter. If you need the code please let me know...

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Make sure it's _minimal_.

Comment: @BryanOakley could you please tell me how to do that? or do you want the entire code?

Comment: @BryanOakley Maybe my code does not tell much about what I want to achieve yet...

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem now. Instead of creating a grid view, I used the treeview/list view. The gui looks neat! Here is a [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqPrX.png).